# python pandas DataFrame - assign a list to multiple cells

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, valueerror

I have a DataFrame like

```
name col1 col2
 a    aa   123
 a    bb   123
 b    aa   234
```

and a list

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

I want to replace the col2 of every row with col1 = 'aa' with the list like

```
name col1     col2
 a    aa   [1, 2, 3]
 a    bb       123
 b    aa   [1, 2, 3]
```

I tried something like

```
df.loc[df[col1] == 'aa', col2] = [1, 2, 3]
```

but it gives me the error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (xx,) into shape (yy,)
```

How should I get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"name":["a","a","b"],"col1":["aa","bb","aa"],"col2":[123,123,234]})
l = [1,2,3]
df["col2"] = df.apply(lambda x: l if x.col1 == "aa" else x.col2, axis =1)
df
```

Answer (score 4):

Make it simple. np.where should do. Code below

```
df['col2']=np.where(df['col1']=='aa', str(lst), df['col2'])
```

Alternatively use pd.Series with list locked in double brackects

```
df['col2']=np.where(df['col1']=='aa', pd.Series([lst]), df['col2'])
```

Comment: Except this doesn't works with a list. You're converting to string here, which would also work with OP's approach.

Comment: OP did specify, made edits though. Pd.Series locks in a list. That can be checked by attempting explode after insertion

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension with an if/else should work

```
df['col2'] = [x['col2'] if x['col1'] != 'aa' else [1,2,3] for ind,x in df.iterrows()]
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be safe to do with for loop

```
df.col2 = df.col2.astype(object)
for x in df.index:
    if df.at[x,'col1'] == 'aa':
       df.at[x,'col2'] = [1,2,3]
       
df
  name col1       col2
0    a   aa  [1, 2, 3]
1    a   bb        123
2    b   aa  [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
data = {'aa':[1,2,3]}
df['col2'] = np.where(df['col1'] == 'aa', df['col1'].map(data), df['col2'])
```

You should use this with care, as doing this will change list to both locations:

```
df['col2'].loc[0].append(5)
print(df)
#OUTPUT
  name col1          col2
0    a   aa  [1, 2, 3, 5]
1    a   bb           123
2    b   aa  [1, 2, 3, 5]
```

But this is fine:

```
df = df.loc[1:]
print(df)
#OUTPUT
  name col1       col2
1    a   bb        123
2    b   aa  [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I think this is different from other proposed solutions as `col2` will contain multiple references to the same list object. I am not sure if this is what OP intends or not.

Comment: Yes you are right, you have to use this with caution.